# Cannot upgrade and install apps

Tags: upgrade, samba

I just started PC and I cannot upgrade apps.

```
tomsk@tomsk-U36SD:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for tomsk: 
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

So I run **sudo dpkg --configure -a** and I got:

```
tomsk@tomsk-U36SD:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up keyboard-configuration (1.108ubuntu15.3) ...
Your console font configuration will be updated the next time your system
boots. If you want to update it now, run 'setupcon' from a virtual console.
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up apt-transport-https (1.2.19) ...
dpkg: error processing package samba-libs:amd64 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Setting up libisc160:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.4) ...
Setting up libgstreamer1.0-0:amd64 (1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1) ...
Setcap worked! gst-ptp-helper is not suid!
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba-vfs-modules:
 samba-vfs-modules depends on samba-libs (= 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package samba-libs:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package samba-vfs-modules (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libisc-export160 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.4) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up update-notifier-common (3.168.3) ...
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: processing...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Setting up sudo (1.8.16-0ubuntu1.3) ...
Setting up isc-dhcp-common (4.3.3-5ubuntu12.6) ...
Setting up libpcsclite1:amd64 (1.8.14-1ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for install-info (6.1.0.dfsg.1-5) ...
Setting up tzdata (2016j-0ubuntu0.16.04) ...

Current default time zone: 'Europe/Prague'
Local time is now:      Út úno 14 08:38:08 CET 2017.
Universal Time is now:  Tue Feb 14 07:38:08 UTC 2017.
Run 'dpkg-reconfigure tzdata' if you wish to change it.

dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mono-devel:
 mono-devel depends on mono-xbuild (= 4.6.2.16-0xamarin1); however:
  Package mono-xbuild is not installed.
 mono-devel depends on libmono-2.0-dev (>= 4.6.2.16-0xamarin1); however:
  Version of libmono-2.0-dev on system is 4.6.2.7-0xamarin2.

dpkg: error processing package mono-devel (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-samba:
 python-samba depends on samba-libs (= 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package samba-libs:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-samba (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libdns-export162 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.4) ...
Setting up libglapi-mesa:amd64 (12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up libglapi-mesa:i386 (12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up libappstream3:amd64 (0.9.4-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libpulse0:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.2) ...
Setting up libpulse0:i386 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.2) ...
Setting up gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 (2.14.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up libdrm2:amd64 (2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Setting up libdrm2:i386 (2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libsmbclient:amd64:
 libsmbclient:amd64 depends on samba-libs (= 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package samba-libs:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libsmbclient:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up isc-dhcp-client (4.3.3-5ubuntu12.6) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Setting up python3-problem-report (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.5) ...
Setting up nano (2.5.3-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libdrm-intel1:amd64 (2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Setting up libdrm-intel1:i386 (2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Setting up libisccc140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.4) ...
Setting up krb5-locales (1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbldap.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetapi.so.0 is not a symbolic link

Processing triggers for doc-base (0.10.7) ...
Processing 2 changed doc-base files...
Registering documents with scrollkeeper...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu16) ...
Setting up liblwres141:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mono-complete:
 mono-complete depends on libmono-2.0-1 (= 4.6.2.16-0xamarin1); however:
  Version of libmono-2.0-1 on system is 4.6.2.7-0xamarin2.
 mono-complete depends on libmono-profiler (= 4.6.2.16-0xamarin1); however:
  Version of libmono-profiler on system is 4.6.2.7-0xamarin2.
 mono-complete depends on mono-jay (= 4.6.2.16-0xamarin1); however:
  Version of mono-jay on system is 4.6.2.7-0xamarin2.
 mono-complete depends on mono-devel (= 4.6.2.16-0xamarin1); however:
  Package mono-devel is not configured yet.
 mono-complete depends on mono-csharp-shell (= 4.6.2.16-0xamarin1); however:
  Version of mono-csharp-shell on system is 4.6.2.7-0xamarin2.
 mono-complete depends on mono-4.0-service (= 4.6.2.16-0xamarin1); however:
  Version of mono-4.0-service on system is 4.6.2.7-0xamarin2.
 mono-complete depends on monodoc-manual (= 4.6.2.16-0xamarin1); however:
  Version of monodoc-manual on system is 4.6.2.7-0xamarin2.
 mono-complete depends on ca-certificates-mon
dpkg: error processing package mono-complete (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up openssl (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.6) ...
Setting up vim-common (2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up snap-confine (2.21) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine ...
Setting up libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (2.14.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up libdrm-radeon1:amd64 (2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Setting up libdrm-radeon1:i386 (2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba:
 samba depends on python-samba; however:
  Package python-samba is not configured yet.
 samba depends on samba-libs (= 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package samba-libs:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libdrm-nouveau2:amd64 (2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Setting up libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Setting up libmonoboehm-2.0-1 (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up console-setup-linux (1.108ubuntu15.3) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/console-setup/compose.ISO-8859-1.inc ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/console-setup/compose.ISO-8859-13.inc ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/console-setup/compose.ISO-8859-14.inc ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/console-setup/compose.ISO-8859-15.inc ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/console-setup/compose.ISO-8859-2.inc ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/console-setup/compose.ISO-8859-3.inc ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/console-setup/compose.ISO-8859-4.inc ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/console-setup/compose.ISO-8859-7.inc ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/console-setup/compose.ISO-8859-9.inc ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba-common-bin:
 samba-common-bin depends on python-samba; however:
  Package python-samba is not configured yet.
 samba-common-bin depends on samba-libs (= 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package samba-libs:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package samba-common-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba-dsdb-modules:
 samba-dsdb-modules depends on samba-libs (= 2:4.3.11+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.3); however:
  Package samba-libs:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package samba-dsdb-modules (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 (8u121-b13-0ubuntu1.16.04.2) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/java-8-openjdk/security/java.security ...
Setting up vim-tiny (2:7.4.1689-3ubuntu1.2) ...
Setting up libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64 (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up console-setup (1.108ubuntu15.3) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Setting up libdns162:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.4) ...
Setting up libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.2) ...
Setting up libpulsedsp:amd64 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.2) ...
Setting up libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Setting up libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 (2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Setting up pulseaudio-utils (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.2) ...
Setting up libosmesa6:i386 (12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up libosmesa6:amd64 (12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up libdrm-dev:amd64 (2.4.70-1~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
Setting up libisccfg140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.4) ...
Setting up libgbm1:amd64 (12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/drirc ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up appstream (0.9.4-1ubuntu2) ...
AppStream cache update completed successfully.
Setting up python3-apport (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.5) ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbldap.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetapi.so.0 is not a symbolic link

Setting up libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbldap.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetapi.so.0 is not a symbolic link

Setting up apport (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.5) ...
Setting up ubuntu-core-launcher (2.21) ...
Setting up libbind9-140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.4) ...
Setting up libegl1-mesa:amd64 (12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbldap.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetapi.so.0 is not a symbolic link

Setting up bind9-host (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.4) ...
Setting up pulseaudio (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.2) ...
Setting up mesa-common-dev:amd64 (12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up pulseaudio-module-x11 (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.2) ...
Setting up apport-gtk (2.20.1-0ubuntu2.5) ...
Setting up dnsutils (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.4) ...
Setting up openjdk-8-jre:amd64 (8u121-b13-0ubuntu1.16.04.2) ...
Setting up libgl1-mesa-dev:amd64 (12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up pulseaudio-module-bluetooth (1:8.0-0ubuntu3.2) ...
Setting up libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 (12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 (2.14.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37-gtk2:amd64 (2.14.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 (2.14.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
Setting up python3-distupgrade (1:16.04.21) ...
Setting up libmono-system-xml4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-security4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up python3-update-manager (1:16.04.5) ...
Setting up ubuntu-release-upgrader-core (1:16.04.21) ...
Setting up libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk (1:16.04.21) ...
Setting up update-manager-core (1:16.04.5) ...
Setting up libmono-system4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up update-notifier (3.168.3) ...
Setting up update-manager (1:16.04.5) ...
Setting up libmono-security4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up mono-4.0-gac (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up mono-gac (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
* Installing 1 assembly from libglade2.0-cil into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from libglib2.0-cil into Mono
* Installing 5 assemblies from libgtk2.0-cil into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from libnunit-console-runner2.6.3-cil into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from libnunit-core2.6.3-cil into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from libnunit-core-interfaces2.6.3-cil into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from libnunit-framework2.6.3-cil into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from libnunit-mocks2.6.3-cil into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from libnunit-util2.6.3-cil into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from libwebkit1.1-cil into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.10.atk-sharp into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.10.gdk-sharp into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.10.glade-sharp into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.10.glib-sharp into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.10.gtk-dotnet into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.10.gtk-sharp into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.10.pango-sharp into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.4.atk-sharp into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.4.gdk-sharp into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.4.glade-sharp into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.4.glib-sharp into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.4.gtk-dotnet into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.4.gtk-sharp into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.4.pango-sharp into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.atk-sharp into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.gdk-sharp into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.glade-sharp into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.glib-sharp into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.gtk-dotnet into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.gtk-sharp into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.nunit-console-runner into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.nunit.core into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.nunit.core.interfaces into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.nunit.framework into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.nunit.mocks into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.nunit.util into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.6.pango-sharp into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.8.atk-sharp into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.8.gdk-sharp into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.8.glade-sharp into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.8.glib-sharp into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.8.gtk-dotnet into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.8.gtk-sharp into Mono
* Installing 1 assembly from policy.2.8.pango-sharp into Mono
Setting up mono-runtime-common (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up mono-runtime-sgen (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up mono-runtime (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-corlib4.5-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-rabbitmq4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up mono-utils (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-runtime-serialization-formatters-soap4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-posix4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-peapi4.0a-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-cscompmgd0.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-numerics4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-webbrowser4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-windows4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-deployment4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-web-mobile4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-xbuild-tasks4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-sharpzip4.84-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-servicemodel-internals0.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-microsoft-build-framework4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-runtime-interopservices-runtimeinformation4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-relaxng4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-core4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-microsoft-build4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-data-tds4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-workflow-runtime4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-management4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-i18n4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-accessibility4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-messaging4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-servicemodel-activation4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-workflow-activities4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-cecil-private-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-cairo4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-parallel4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-reflection-context4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-ldap4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-threading-tasks-dataflow4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-dynamic4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-workflow-componentmodel4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-i18n-mideast4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-componentmodel-composition4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-web-regularexpressions4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-web-razor2.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-web-applicationservices4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-i18n-rare4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-compilerservices-symbolwriter4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-ldap4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-simd4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-configuration-install4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-ldap-protocols4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-tasklets4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-net-http4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-debugger-soft4.0a-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-custommarshalers4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-csharp4.0c-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-net4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-transactions4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-microsoft-visualc10.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-json4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-numerics-vectors4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-i18n-other4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-management4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-net-http-webrequest4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-i18n-cjk4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-reactive-interfaces2.2-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-runtime-serialization4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-io-compression4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-microsoft-build-utilities-v4.0-4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-enterpriseservices4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-data4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-io-compression-filesystem4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-identitymodel4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-db2-1.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-data-linq4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-smdiagnostics0.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-webmatrix-data4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-xaml4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-componentmodel-dataannotations4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-windowsbase4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-oracle4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-runtime-caching4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-i18n-west4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-messaging-rabbitmq4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-codecontracts4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-sqlite4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-i18n4.0-all (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-microsoft-csharp4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-identitymodel-selectors4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-json-microsoft4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-xml-linq4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up mono-mcs (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-web4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-reactive-core2.2-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-data-datasetextensions4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-data-entity4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-data-services-client4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-microsoft-build-engine4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-runtime4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-windows-forms-datavisualization4.0a-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-microsoft-web-infrastructure1.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-web-abstractions4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-reactive-windows-forms2.2-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-messaging4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-serviceprocess4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-reactive-runtime-remoting2.2-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-runtime-durableinstancing4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up monodoc-base (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-web-routing4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-drawing-design4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-http4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-reactive-windows-threading2.2-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-design4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-microsoft-build-tasks-v4.0-4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-web-extensions-design4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-net-http-formatting4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-reactive-linq2.2-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-web-http4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-reactive-experimental2.2-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-web-webpages-deployment2.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-web-webpages2.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-web-services4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-servicemodel4.0a-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-web-http-webhost4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-reactive-debugger2.2-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-reactive-providers2.2-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-web-webpages-razor2.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-servicemodel-discovery4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-servicemodel-routing4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-reactive-platformservices2.2-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-reactive-observable-aliases0.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-web-extensions4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-xml-serialization4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-web-http-selfhost4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-web-mvc3.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-web-dynamicdata4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-servicemodel-web4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-system-data-services4.0-cil (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Setting up libmono-cil-dev (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-47-generic
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbldap.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetapi.so.0 is not a symbolic link

Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba-libs:amd64
 samba-vfs-modules
 mono-devel
 python-samba
 libsmbclient:amd64
 mono-complete
 samba
 samba-common-bin
 samba-dsdb-modules
tomsk@tomsk-U36SD:~$
```

**sudo apt-get install -f**

```
I already trust 173, your new list has 173
Import process completed.
Done
done.
Setting up mono-complete (4.6.2.16-0xamarin1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbldap.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetapi.so.0 is not a symbolic link

Errors were encountered while processing:
 samba-libs:amd64
 python-samba
 samba-common-bin
 samba
 libsmbclient:amd64
 samba-dsdb-modules
 samba-vfs-modules
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
tomsk@tomsk-U36SD:~$
```

Comment: nothing I just started notebook after 2 months

Comment: Nothing? I see references to `samba` and `mono` among others that aren't part of a default installation. So, what did you installed (or tried to) before this happened?

Comment: I dont know what is samba, and mono I installed long time ago (to run Open Hardware Monitor), so is safe to remove samba?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it using

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq
```